# Basic CRUD application using SpringMvc hibernate MySql and maven

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, maven

I'm a beginner in spring and hibernate Frameworks and all I need is a CRUD app complete and working tutorial to start. I tried many tutorials but none of them worked for me :( I'll be so glad if someone could possibly help me..
  Have a great day

Comment: Did you tried the tutorials in [**`https://www.youtube.com/`**](https://www.youtube.com/)?

Comment: It is best that you try first and post the issues you face during the development. You can post what didn't work and what you have tried.

Comment: @RossiRobinsion I actually tried, the issue I'm getting now is this error: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory'

Comment: You should post your code and stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer bellow link for basic tutorial spring and hibernate Frameworks with mysql database creation.:

http://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial

https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html

Comment: Can this be in comment?

Comment: Sure. I'm adding a comment bellow.. what other files you need to see ?

Answer (score 0):

this is my spring-servlet.xml file

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CountryData" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>org.arpit.java2blog.model.Country</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>

    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="org.arpit.java2blog" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```